# Android: TextView.setSpan with Bitmap in chat application

Tags: android, bitmap, textview

I am trying to update a single TextView with a bitmap, and then be able to append text directly after.

```
String str = tvChat.getText()+message+"\n"+"   ";
int length = str.length();
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(getActivity(), bm, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);   
ssb.setSpan(span, length-2, length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
tvChat.setText(ssb);
ssb.clear();
ssb.clearSpans();
```

This works for the first time. However when I do this from another part of my code:

```
tvChat.append("Some random text");
```

The images are reposted into the TextView. I would like to add normal text after the image.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the text append just after the image, you must use Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE instead of Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE.

```
ssb.setSpan(span, length-2, length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```